# Get respectives values from Django annotate method

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I have the following `query`:

```
result = data.values('collaborator').annotate(amount=Count('cc'))
top = result.order_by('-amount')[:3]
```

This one, get the `collaborator` field from data, data is a Django [`Queryset`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/), i am trying to make like a `GROUP BY` query, and it's functional, but when i call the [`.values()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#values) method on the `top` variable, it's returning all the models instances as dicts into a queryset, i need the [`annotate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) method result as a list of dicts:
The following is the `top` variable content on shell:

```
<QuerySet [{'collaborator': '1092788966', 'amount': 20}, {'collaborator': '1083692812', 'amount': 20}, {'collaborator': '1083572767', 'amount': 20}]>
```

But when i make `list(top.values())` i get the following result:

```
[{'name': 'Alyse Caffin', 'cc': '1043346592', 'location': 'Wu’an', 'gender': 'MASCULINO', 'voting_place': 'Corporación Educativa American School Barranquilla', 'table_number': '6', 'status': 'ESPERADO', 'amount': 1}, {'name': 'Barthel Hanlin', 'cc': '1043238706', 'location': 'General Santos', 'gender': 'MASCULINO', 'voting_place': 'Colegio San José – Compañía de Jesús Barranquilla', 'table_number': '10', 'status': 'PENDIENTE', 'amount': 1}, {'name': 'Harv Gertz', 'cc': '1043550513', 'location': 'Makueni', 'gender': 'FEMENINO', 'voting_place': 'Corporación Educativa American School Barranquilla', 'table_number': '7', 'status': 'ESPERADO', 'amount': 1}]
```

I just want the result to be like:

```
[{'collaborator': '1092788966', 'amount': 20}, {'collaborator': '1083692812', 'amount': 20}, {'collaborator': '1083572767', 'amount': 20}]
```

Answer (score 0):

there is something wrong, maybe a typo (also it seems you do not show the full query... something like data=yourmodel.objects.filter... is missing before):

The output of list(top.values()) returns a completely different model's fields then what you post as top Queryset- are you sure you really did:

```
result = data.values('collaborator').annotate(amount=Count('cc'))
top = result.order_by('-amount')[:3]
list(top.values())
```

because it should deliver what you expect (provided that data is a Queryset)

Comment: data = Sympathizer.objects.filter(collaborator__token__candidate=pk)

Comment: It's like parsing the model objects as dicts

Comment: And i just want the collaborator field and the amount

Comment: as "collaborator" does not appear in the result of list(top.values()), i suppose that in this case you hold a completely different queryset in "top" - at least not the one that you create with result = data.values('collaborator')....

Comment: "collaborator" is a many to many relation field into the Sympathizer model.

Comment: i just solved it, using list comprehension over the top variable, like: [value for value in top], i don't even know how performant is this, what do you think?